# How to resize the view of specific software

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resizing

Looking at the image attached the problem is self-explanatory. The tabs and icons within the software (photoshop in this particular case) are extremely small so that they are barely visible and difficult to use.
It happens to some of the software just installed in a newly bought pc(very high resolution screen).

How can I resize them specifically (I know the trick for general resizing).

Would the software "sizer" help?

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? How is it self explanatory?

Comment: The question is not self-explanatory. We now have to make guesses as to what you mean. Does your new computer have a very high-resolution screen? Is the scaling not working properly? Have you adjusted scaling and followed the instructions (sign out, and then sign back in after changing the scaling)? Which program(s) is this a problem in?

Comment: hi @cybernetic.nomad, thanks for the comments. I edited the text to explain the problem better.

Comment: hi @music2myear I do not know how to change the scaling, can you be more specific?

Comment: It looks like specific programs don't size the application icons to a usable size on the hi-resolution screen?  So you need a way to adjust the size of the UI components at the application level?  I suspect that will be different for every application, if the application even has the capability.  It would be better for the OS to better communicate a global setting (which is where the applications get the information from).

Comment: @fixer1234 that's exactly it: programs don't size the application icons to a usable size on the hi-resolution screen. I have to idea how to fix it, in photoshop cs6 I could not find any option to do that.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "software sizer"? Please clarify this. Scaling is set in Settings > Display and is the standard method of resizing applications and screen elements for visual issues and high-resolution screens.

Comment: hi @music2myear as I explain in the post scaling using Setting > Display adjusts the resizing of ALL the apps, I would like something targeted to specific apps. Here you find the software sizer http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/

Comment: Your screenshot indicates to me that while your desktop items are scaling, that application is not, which sometimes happens with particularly poorly written programs. When you change the scaling settings on your computer, does this program scale?

Comment: Also, per-app scaling was asked and answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/952120/windows-10-per-app-scaling

Comment: @music2myear thank you for the link, yes is my same question but the question is very old and I did not find the solution I post below.

Comment: @music2myear I agree it might be a duplicate of the suggested post, however the suggested solution does not solve the issue for many apps. Shall I add my answer to the mentioned post and close mine?

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED
I found a solution to set the DPI as best for the application and not the screen resolution for each app.

Right click on the software icon/link > properties > tab "compatibility"> change high DPI setting > mark the checkbox "override high DPI scaling behavior"> select system in the window below (the default is "application")