# Enlarge a specific application in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

There is just this one program that I run where the font is annoyingly small and I got no way to change it. So I got to lean forward to read the text on a 4K monitor. The windows magnifying glass is not what I am looking for because I am have no other problems with reading other things on the screen. I just want this one application window to become scaled up.

In the control panel you can enlarge the entire desktop or each screen individually though a slider. It is possible to do this for a specific application?

Comment: Higher resolution monitors are a huge problem for win32 application they do not scale based on the screen resolution the same way Window Store applications (UWP) scale.  Microsoft is working to address this problem through various improvements to Windows 10, many of those, will be in the Windows 10 Anniversary Edition update due Summer 2016.  It is worth pointing out that most desktop operating systems have this same problem.  To put it in perspective, the same method to scale a resolution was fine for over 20 years, it only recently become a problem UHD and Retina Displays.

Comment: The font for menus, icon text and other things are fixable in the advanced settings for display in the control panel where you can set the font to a bigger size. So I don't think this is a problem for Windows except in special cases like this where the font is hard coded. I also don't enable any compatibility for it to run.

Comment: This is not a Question and Answer forum, What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Comment: As there isn't a solution right now I a added a feature request on Microsofts Feedback Hub for this: https://aka.ms/AAb5aq5

Comment: This could possibly be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/66101/set-dpi-of-individual-applications-in-windows. However to flag this as duplicate, the description says: "This question has been asked before and *already has an answer.*" (emphasis added by me). The accepted answer for the other question just says, it can't be done, so that's not exactly a real solution to this qestion...

Answer (score 15):

Right click the program and click "Properties".
Go to "Compatibility" (if you can't see this, this answer won't work for you).
Click on Override High DPI Scaling Behavior.
Choose System (Enhanced) from the drop down menu.

Voila!
You have got "normal" size on your programme.

Comment: This was close to what I needed to do for one application, except I had to Select 'System', which worked perfectly.  System (Enhanced) resulted in a messed up layout with tiny text.

Comment: what "desk icon"? Some punctuation making it clear which is each instruction could help this as well...

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me,

Comment: Thanks mate you saved my bacon!!!

Answer (score 4):

I would say that some programs are just coded that way, for example take Photoshop here. I'm running Windows in 125% DPI Scaled mode and look at the menu:

[image]

But I know the way that will probably work for some small programs, like Installations and such. I'm gonna use SFX Setup as a example for this.

Go [here](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/#download) and choose either first or second option (I prefer first because it adds a entry menu when right clicking on a .exe or .dll, pretty neat)

1. Right click on the file you want to modify and choose **Open using Resource Hacker**

[image]

2. At the left pane, if you find **Dialog** folder than it means you can probably modify it, but keep in mind that this isn't always the case.
   When you expand the folder, you should see a lot of dialog resources depending on what program you're trying to modify.

[image]

3. Modify the 5th line of the code where it says **FONT 8**, this can differ from program to program, you can also define your own font where it says **"MS Shell Dlg 2"**

[image]

Here I've put the number 9 instead of 8 and then hit F5 to compile it, or click on the green arrow button in the upper menu. You can see how the window expanded a bit and how the elements are bigger.

[image]

Now go save the file.

[image]

If the filename was **candy.exe**, name it something else like **candy new version.exe** to avoid any corruption because it will happen from time to time with .exe or .dll files.

[image]

and here is the example:

[image]

Comment: If it had worked just not it would be genius