# Windows app appear too small on high resolution displays

Tags: windows, resolution

Is there a way to "zoom" specific applications (and not all apps) to prevent them from getting too small to view for high-resolution monitors?

For example, my display already has this 3240x2160 resolution with a 200% scale, but some applications appear too small, such as the Smart PSS app.

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1069620/enlarge-a-specific-application-in-windows-10

Comment: @Gantendo thanks, that actually solved it