# Windows 11 Alderlake 12900KF at 100% on ALL cores

Tags: cpu-usage, windows-11, intel-core-i9

My new Alderlake 12900KF is running most time at 100% an ALL 24 virtual cores with temperature and fan speed going up as well. Directly after startup everything seems to be fine, but after a while load goes up. Tried to shutdown services and running programs one by one with no effect. On old i7 same setup used a few percent on a few cores normally.

Will appreciate any ideas to solve or further debug this behaviour, could provide more information if you want. Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot of resmon and task scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdtUi.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Corsair.Service.exe - High CPU Usage](https://forum.corsair.com/forums/topic/163320-corsairserviceexe-high-cpu-usage/)
may relate to your problem.

I note that the only solution for the participants in the post was to
eradicate all Corsair software, even at the loss of some functionality.

If you try to do the same, use an advanced uninstaller such as
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/).

But above all, ensure that you can uninstall back the Corsair software
that you remove, in case it turns out not to have been the source of
the problem.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1069620/enlarge-a-specific-application-in-windows-10

Comment: thanks for your answer @harrymc, but  corsair wasn't the problem. After starting computer today problem is gone without changing anything. Can't reproduce that strange problem either.

Comment: : OK, understood.