# How to make Windows 10 draw a window at 100% scaling, rather than 125%?

Tags: windows-10, high-dpi

I have a small, high-resolution display that is set at 125%. However, one program I want to run consistently draws it's start screen at 1024x768, which is a tad too big for my screen.

I want this program, and only this program, to render at 100% rather than 125%.

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE.** This program **is DPI-aware** and thus "Disable display scaling" won't work on it.

So, I see two options:

1. Tell Windows to inform this program it's running at 96 DPI, and draw it as such.
2. Have Windows scale the program ***down*** to fit.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If is is a high resolution screen how can a 1024 by 768 window be too big? What program is it actually?

Comment: @Seth Open Rails Train Simulator. The screen is high resolution but it's resolution is only 1280x800. The program fits if I set DPI scaling to 100% for the system.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://openrails.org/files/ORv645_StartUp_Documentation_Final.pdf) you could choose to run it "Full Screen" or you could use configuration options/[startup parameters](https://www.trainsim.com/vbts/showthread.php?210627-Resolution-and-command-line-flags-Questions) to set the actual resolution for the window. You could also check [Set DPI of individual applications in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/66101/set-dpi-of-individual-applications-in-windows).

Comment: @Seth unfortuantely that's not the problem. the issue is the `Menu.exe` screen, not the game itself.

Comment: "Set DPI of individual applications" only works for non DPI-aware applications.