# Set Scaling of individual applications in Windows

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, scaling, 4k-resolution

I occurs to be that I want any app I'm not looking at to be scaled down (to say 100%), but the one in focus to be scaled up (to 200%). This would both make maximal use of my hi-res laptop screen for peripheral vision and give my eyes a rest for the focused task.

I'm not talking about per-application, like [Set DPI of individual applications in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/66101/set-dpi-of-individual-applications-in-windows)

I want any app that supports scaling to be re-scaled when I'm looking at it.

The magnifier sucks, in case you thought of that :)

I'm supposing it needs to be an autohotkey (AHK) script.

Comment: AutoHotkey would make quick work of detecting window changes and applying a setting to the newly focused and newly out-of-focus window.  Do you know what setting or command would need to be applied on a per-window basis, or is that part of your question as well, i.e., to come up with such a mechanism.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is part of my question. Thanks!

Comment: To create such an AutoHotKey script, we would need an API to zoom individual applications or set their DPI scaling. As AFAIK there isn't such an API, I posted an issue on Microsofts Feedback Hub: https://aka.ms/AAb5aq5