# How to magnify or change the DPI on one screen only in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dpi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual monitors on Windows 7 - How do I set a different DPI or text size on each monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/29796/dual-monitors-on-windows-7-how-do-i-set-a-different-dpi-or-text-size-on-each-mo)

I am using a secondary monitor with a laptop. The laptop is 1920x1200 and the 1280 x1024. The issue is that the laptop monitor is fairly small while the secondary monitor is relative large. I find the laptop not comfortable to read at at 3.5' ~ 4' away but if I change the default DPI for the system it makes things in the second monitor look huge. Is there a setting or an app that can set a DPI for one screen while keeping the other the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the **[Windows 7 Magnifier](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Make-items-on-the-screen-appear-bigger-Magnifier)** tool...

There are options to magnify

- the whole screen
- part of the screen
- or a selection of the screen

Tutorial from [Online Tech Tips](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/):

> [Use All the Features of the Windows 7 Magnifier Program](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/use-all-the-features-of-windows-7-magnifier-program/)

Comment: Sorry to -1 vote you, but this is not a complete solution, primarily due to the Tracking "feature" that is implemented by Windows 7. I believe the OP was asking how to keep a consistent magnification on the secondary laptop screen, which is the same problem I'm having.