# Apply display magnification to just one monitor

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution, external-display, magnifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual monitors on Windows 7 - How do I set a different DPI or text size on each monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/29796/dual-monitors-on-windows-7-how-do-i-set-a-different-dpi-or-text-size-on-each-mo)

I recently got a new work laptop. It supports a really high widescreen resolution of 1920 x 1080. I have an external monitor too, so I extend my desktop to that. I use [UltraMon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraMon) to manage my separate taskbars and wallpapers.

I discovered that the computer came on the highest resolution with a magnification at 125%. When I moved it down to 100% I realized it's way too small and it hurts my eye, so I bumped it back up to 125%. This 125% looks bad on my external monitor though. How can I apply some sort of magnification on my laptop display, but not on the monitor?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that are not directly related to magnification but may help you out.

1. In Windows 7, use Display-> Screen Resolution to adjust the resolution of the specific display that is bothering you. This may not be perfect, but it's a quick fix.
2. More specifically, if you have a Nvidia card in your laptop, NVIDIA Control Panel has a cool feature under 'Manage custom resolutions' that will allow you to set a custom resolution with finer control than Windows. Click 'Create' and the 'Bits per pixel' setting should let you lower or raise the bits per pixel setting to force a magnification increase or decrease.

Comment: This addresses the user's problem, which unfortunately has nothing to do with the question that was actually asked! I really do want to magnify a region on one monitor, much like the built-in "Magnifier" tool, rather than change the resolution, while working on the other monitor - which seems impossible because the magnifier always follows mouse or keyboard focus, with no option to turn that off. Bonus points if you can find an answer to the question that was asked instead of just the question that was meant :)