# How do I set different text sizes for different monitors?

Tags: windows, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual monitors on Windows - How do I set a different DPI or text size on each monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/29796/dual-monitors-on-windows-how-do-i-set-a-different-dpi-or-text-size-on-each-mon)

I have a 15" laptop running Windows 7, which I also connect to a 24" monitor at work. I want to change the text size only on the 15" laptop monitor, to 150%, but on the 24" monitor I want to go with the default 100% text size, since the monitor is big and I can see the letters clearly.

How do I set the text size per monitor?

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically?

Comment: I'm quite sure you can't do that. How would the system handle windows that span on the two monitors?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/29796/dual-monitors-on-windows-7-how-do-i-set-a-different-dpi-or-text-size-on-each-m <-- because of the way it works those answers pretty much cover it. the only other possibility would be to change actual resolution to the monitor itself, which some people will do, because they want to read easily, vrses the ugly interpolated rendering.

Comment: no, I dont want to do this programmatically.

Comment: I understand that there is no way to do it, but just a clarification, only the text size needs to be different. All other graphics, windows and dialogs will always resort to the native resolution of the monitor. I believe the limitation is that the display driver can handle only one text size for all monitors. Technically it should be possible, its just that the no one in microsoft's display driver team has thought about it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in any way. This mean you just want a single person to handle two PC's  at the same time which could not possible.

Comment: why not? did you understand the question?