# I have two screens with Windows 7, and I want to enlarge one

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual monitors on Windows 7 - How do I set a different DPI or text size on each monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/29796/dual-monitors-on-windows-7-how-do-i-set-a-different-dpi-or-text-size-on-each-m)

I have two screens, one that I use regularly and then my TV that is 32", but a bit away from the desk. I would like to be able to zoom on only the 32" inch tv, but not the regular screen that is 24". It was answered to someone else that you can magnify on the screen, but how do I magnify it without doing it on both screens?

Comment: Are you talking about changing the screen resolution of just one display? Are you using multiple monitor mode or clone?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your TV is digital, it has a native resolution just like your monitor.  If it's a 1080 HD display, the resolution is 1920x1080.  If it's a 720 HD display, it's 1280x720.  In your display settings you can set the resolution for each monitor independently.

[image: Resolution Setting]

If you set your resolution to anything less than the native resolution of the display, everything will look bigger on the screen.  However this may also result in a display that is distorted and fuzzy, possibly to the point of being unusable.  Try a lower resolution that is an exact fraction of the native resolution.  If the display is 1920x1080, try 1280x720 setting - exactly 2/3rds of the native resolution.

It's easy to apply any new resolution to see what it looks like (click Apply, not OK).  Windows will ask if you want to keep the new resolution.  Good luck!