# How to increase readability on 1 screen only?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, readability

As topic says, how to go about improving the readability on 1 screen only?

I have a 1080p Laptop monitor, and a 24" 1920x1200 2nd screen, now it's quite hard to read text without zooming in on the laptop monitor.. In Windows you can set text and other items to medium or even large, but that makes the icons and stuff on my 2nd screen unnecessary large.

Laptop: Dell Latitude E6530, Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: [DPI is the same on both screens for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/29796/dual-monitors-on-windows-how-do-i-set-a-different-dpi-or-text-size-on-each-mon).  The upcoming Windows 8.1 release however will [allow different DPI settings on different monitors](http://www.osnews.com/story/27190/Windows_8_1_introduces_per-monitor_DPI_scaling).