# How to make text sharp both on 15" laptop screen and 27" external monitor?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

Both screens are full HD resolution. On Laptop (15") I have set text size to 125% for readability.

On external monitor (27") is text size 100%, but the text is blurry. When changing the size to 125%, as on my primary screen, text is sharp, but also big and I am loosing the benefit of big screen size.

I am extending screens.

Is there a way how to make text on both screen look sharp with different settings? I am running on Windows 10.

**EDIT**

In Chrome and Visual studio (and all other apps) the text is blurry on external monitor (100%). But SQL management studio is sharp on external monitor and blurry on laptop screen (125%), Chrome and VS are sharp on laptop.

**EDIT**

I have found this answer: https://superuser.com/a/954582/284796 but it is not working for me because, my laptop screen supports text up to 175%, not 200% as proposed in the answer. As well I would like to keep my laptop text size to 125%.

Comment: do you mirror your desktop or extend it?

Comment: If your external monitor is running at its native resolution, text should not be blurry at 100% size. Is ClearType configured correctly?

Comment: I am extending screens. And I tried to run ClearType configuration on external display, while text size was 100%, but there was no difference, it was still blurry.

Comment: Is the blurred text an issue in certain programs or is it all text on that monitor is blurry.

Comment: In chrome and visual studio text is blurry on external monitor (100%). But SQL management studio is sharp on external monitor and blurry on laptop screen (125%), while the other two are sharp there.